# VBA: Creating Macro in Excel - Compile Error -- 'Sub or function is not defined'

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, excel-2010

I have a workbook with several sheets with tables on them. I want to aggregate all the rows from the sheets onto the main table in the first. I would like it to be dynamic, so  that when I add a row to one of the other sheets, it adds the row to the main table. Here is the code for my Sub:

```
Public Sub AggregateIssues() 
    For pgNum = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(pgNum).Name = "Main" Then

          currSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(pgNum) 'Get Sheet
          flag = True
          RowIndex = 0
          While currSheet.Tables(0).Rows(RowIndex).Cells(0).Text = Null Or currSheet.Tables(0).Rows(RowIndex).Cells(0).Text = ""

            Row = currSheet.Tables(0).Rows(RowIndex)
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Tables("MainTbl").Append (Row)
            RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
          Next
        End If
    Next pgNum
End Sub
```

Currently, I am getting a compile error: `Sub or function is not defined`. The error is thrown on the name of the sub. This is the definition. Of course it is not defined yet. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Note: I believe the error is actually be caused by the `continue` keyword. Is there a `continue` keyword in VBA?

Comment: `continue` is not used in VBA - that will not compile: neither will `break`

Comment: Is there comparable keywords?

Comment: Just wrap that `if` around the rest of the code in the loop (changing = to <>). Instead of break you want `Exit` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I wrapped most of the code in the first if and switch to `<>` and then put the next if condition in the while loop. I'm getting a `Next with no For` on the Next for the While loop. Is that the wrong syntax?

Comment: @TimWilliams If you want to put your comments in a answer i'll mark it as answered. Your comments helped me work through my inital issue.

Comment: Most things are not zero-indexed in VBA, so (eg) `Cells(0)` should be `Cells(1)` and `Rows(0)` should be `Rows(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`continue` is not used in VBA - you can instead wrap that `if` around the code in the main loop.

`break` is not a VBA statement either - you probably want `Exit` in place of that.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your Update1,

The problem is in your While loop.

The correct format is this:

```
Do while [boolean expression]
'do something
Loop
```

To be more specific add `Do` before `While`, and change your first `Next` to `Loop`

Technically you can also use this structure which I like for nostalgic reasons:

```
While [boolean expression]
'do something
Wend
```

but you should use the [Do...Loop structure (click link for examples)](http://www.vbtutor.net/vba/vba5.htm)

Edit: To clarify, do not include the [] in your actual code. :-)